# Can a bad bootloader brick a microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, bootloader, cortex-m

My question is, if I manage to develop some kind of bootloader and flash it (is it called that when you put a bootloader on an MCU?), and it works horribly, can it brick the MCU entirely, making it completely unusable, permanently?

The reason I'm asking is that I've been tasked to develop a bootloader for the STM32F407. Problem is, I don't know anything about bootloaders or anything of the sort, which means that I have a lot to learn.
I appreciate any answers, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, absolutely, I have a collection of bricked microcontrollers, every so often I get lazy and there goes another.

It is very specific to your microcontroller and family.  For example, pin count is very important, as much bang for your buck as you can get, if your microcontroller relies on certain pins for in circuit (or even in a programming fixture) and those pins can be repurposed by software.  For example jtag pins that can also be gpio pins.  And your code for some reason uses them as gpio pins, AND the design of the chip is such that they cannot use the jtag interface when the chip is in reset, then you can get bricked.

Another very easy one is the pll or clocks in general.  If/as you develop code to initialize the clock system (assuming you choose to do that, even if you use chip vendor supplied code) and you have a bug that switches the chip over to a clock that you have not properly initialized or isnt there, it might brick.

Now some chip designs, many, help you out in various ways.  The AVR family in general there is a programming mode that happens while the chip is in reset or is related to reset such that whatever code is in flash cannot affect its functionality, you can have a bad board design, sure, but your code cannot prevent it from working.  Another method is a "strap" a pin (or pins) that is dedicated to a boot function, set one way normal boot, tie it the other and it goes into an alternate bootloader.  This is what you have on the stm32 boot0 and sometimes boot1 depending.  that is your get out of jail free card for that chip family, if you brick your chip (pll/clock or mess up the SWD pins by using them as gpio), you "simply" change boot0 and it boots into an internal bootloader (which AFAIK you cant mess up) which is known to work.  From that bootloader you can use SWD (chips not bricked now) or the bootloader itself (always serial, sometimes usb or other is supported).  NXP similar deal.  Atmel ARMs used to have (do have) SAM-BA now they really only support SWD, you can get some samba code and try to lock it into the flash, but way too easy to unlock and or trash that flash, so that is a fail on their part.

As part of your system design if you dont have one of these built into save you from bricking features (like boot0 on an STM32), then I recommend you add one.  Very early code initializes a dedicated gpio pin as a strap into your software, if that gpio pin is pulled one way do a normal boot, if pulled the other then spin in an infinite loop or jump to some other guaranteed to not be buggy code.  Not a complete guarantee that you wont build the project wrong and trash this code, but it at least allows you to develop your bootloader/project and not brick a tray full of parts/boards as you work through the peripherals that can brick it.

Note letting smoke out of the part is another way to brick it as well, and that can/does happen from time to time as well.

Lots of examples on how to boot an STM32, plus various code from ST that you can use as a starting point as well.  (all of which is of various quality, you get what you pay for).  Their docs are good, better than some of the competition, not difficult at all to boot and configure their peripherals, sometimes easier than trying to use a canned library. YMMV, you should try various solutions.  But if you are new to this, bricking is highly likely, fortunately you have a chip that you cant brick so long as your board design breaks out the boot0 pin.  For a prototype board for an STM32 I prefer to have a boot0 button and a reset button, just reset resets the chip and runs, hold boot0 and press reset and it goes into the bootloader.  both have to be wired in properly with the right pull up or down as needed for this task.  or a jumper works tie boot0 directly high or low then pop reset, costs you more time, but works.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you. I'll accept your answer and be extremely careful when developing. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

In short no you cannot brick a microcontroller with a bootloader.
In the end bootloader is just a firmware and can be erased away using the programmer via SWD
Erase the flash and your controller is as good as new

Comment: Yes, correct answer! ... And AFAIK some STMs have built-in bootloader (embedded, in ROM area), so why bother writing another one?

Comment: @groenhen You need a custom bootloader for any kind of ICP which is not over the default interface(s) using STM's protocol, e.g. if your firmware comes encrypted or over some WiFi interface.

Comment: @JimmyB: yes agree, yet custom bootloader is another story. But OP asked if it's possible to brick the micro via bootloader. The answer is simple: Even if you play with settings/fuses, etc, you can still recover the controller by simply erasing it with a programmer. Once I recovered an AVR (after playing with CLK fuses) using a RC oscillator (ext.circuit) and of course a AVR-ISP programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can brick the Micro controller to never recovered state. I did this and i did it in STM32F427.

Bootloader is all about carefully selecting Clocks, Peripharals and Interrupts priority. if you do this, there are less chances to brick the controller. Also test everything before release your code as some companies wants to save proprietary information to be saved so they blow up the JTAG lines, the only way to program is via Bootloader and if it is not perfect, voila, you just bricked the controller.